# Impact of Masters thesis on PhD application

Tags: phd, thesis, masters, application

I am a final year masters student and I will be defending in Fall 2020. I will be applying for PhD in Fall 2021. At the start of my Masters thesis, me and my PI had a specific goal in mind (lets call it Goal A). But unfortunately, we got stuck at a particular problem along the way for nearly three months before we could figure it out. Consequently, we made the decision to cut short the thesis to a smaller chunk (lets call it Goal A'). Now here are the couple of questions I have.

1. The schools that I am targeting work in A, is it a bad thing to have not achieved A in my masters thesis?
2. Is cutting short the thesis a bad thing? Does it give the application committee a bad impression on the candidate?
3. I will be working on the original goal (the goal A) in the 7 month period after I graduate my masters. Should I mention this in my Statement of Purpose? Does it balance out the fact that I was not able to work on it in my masters?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: That's research! I think anywhere you apply will understand that.

Comment: What count and will be useful is what you have learned. Forget achievements or marks.